# Relation between the new and old variances when an item (greater than the mean) is added

Tags: statistics

Let X = {x(i)} be a group of n data with mean = μ(x) and variance $= σ(x)^2$.

We use the symbol S(x(i)) to represent the sum of all the x's.

Similar notations will be used for the group Y.

Supposed that Y is formed by adding an extra element x(n+1) to X and the value of that element is greater than μ(x).

That is, [x(n+1) = μ(x) + d; where d > 0].

Then we have μ(y)  > μ(x) because

$μ(y) = [S(x(i)) + (μ(x) + d)] / (n + 1)$

$= [(S(x(i)) + μ(x)) + d] / (n + 1)$

$= [(nμ(x) + μ(x) + d] / (n + 1)$

$= [(n + 1) μ(x) + d] / (n + 1)$

$= μ(x) + [d / (n + 1)]$

$> μ(x)$

From which, we can say that:-
 “if an item greater than the mean is added, the new mean is greater than the original.”
The actual relation between μx and μy is μ(y) = μ(x) + δ; where δ = d / (n + 1).

I am trying to get a simple and nice relation between $σ(x)^2$ and $σ(y)^2$ too. Using the similar derivation method as above, the closest I can get is $σ(y)^2 > n σ(x)^2 / (n + 1)$.

Is the above conclusion correct? Or is it possible to go further to get a much more simpler relation like $σ(y)^2 > σ(x)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

From linearity of expectation, you can say that $\mu (X) + \mu(x_{n+1}) = \mu(Y)$ which may be a simpler relation than a scaling ratio, wich may not always be true. For the variance of the new sum, you need to know if your data are correlated or not. For uncorrelated data, the variance of Y will be equal to the the variance of X + variance of the added item. For correlated data, you will need to adjust for the covariance between the added data element and the elements in X.

Comment: I think we are talking about uncorrelated data. I will upload my derivation (in image) as an answer to my question. The result turned out to be slightly different than yours. May be one of the squared term can compensate to form var(X) instead of var(X)*n/(n+1).

Comment: In your derivation of your original post, I don't know why divide by n+1. The mean of S(X) = n$\mu_x$ and the mean of $x_{n+1}$ = $\mu_x + \delta$. Therefore, the mean of the new sum Y = X + $x_{n+1}$ is $(n+1)\mu_x + \delta$. Also, if is the sum of the previous n terms plus a new, higher mean term, its mean will not, as you show in your deriviation, be $\mu_x + \delta$ that is the mean of $x_{n+1}$ not the mean of Y. I think that is the cause of the difference.

Comment: This is just the first part of my reply. (1) After adding the extra data ($x_{n+1}$) to X, Y has n(Y) elements and n(Y) = n(X) + 1 = n + 1. (2) If n(Y) = n + 1, [1/(n + 1)] will be used to calculate var(Y).

Comment: Mick - you are confusing the sample calculations with the moment calculations. Y is a sum of random variables, with n having $\mu(x)$ and another having a different, higher mean. The expected value and variance can be derived using addition. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_.28Bienaym.C3.A9_formula.29

Answer (score 0):

The following is my derivation (in image because it is easier type in WORD than in LaTex).[image: Change in Variance]

Comment: See my comment below. I think the issue is that in your post, you define Y as a sum of terms, while in the derivation above and in your conclusions, you treat Y as a new data point. There is only a single Y variable and n+1 x's.

Comment: Given that X = {x(1), x(2), …, x(n)} is a group of n data with mean = μ(x, n). Y is formed by adding one more element [called x(n+1)] to X such that Y = {x(1), x(2), …, x(n), x(n+1)} which has n + 1 elements in total. Thus, the mean for Y is μ(y, n+1). Sorry that I don’t understand why you said “you define Y as a sum of terms” and “(in the derivation and conclusions, I have treated) Y as a new data point. There is only a single Y variable and n+1 x's.”

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more consistent with your terminology. $\mu(x,n)$ is not a standard notation. You indicate in line two of our original post that each of the elements of X have the same mean, since you use $S(x_i) = n\mu(x)$ This problem is very straigntforward. You add expected values and variances for indpendent variables. The relation is addition.